# Значение в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Как проверить в регулярном выражении на существовании определенного атрибута и если он есть, то выполнить манипуляции, если нет, то не выполнять.
Можно сделать типа такого:

```
preg_replace("#\[font|font size=(1|2|3)\](.+?)\[\/font\]#is", "...", $text);
```

Но атрибут size может быть передан, а может быть и не передан. Так же, нужно будет сверять значение атрибута, если он был передан:

```
switch($size){
case '1': $f='font-style:10pt;';
case '2': $f='font-style:11pt;';
}
```

Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: хм... а чем preg_match_all вас не устроил?

Comment: понимаешь ты хоть что делает **[preg_replace][1]**??? и что такое $size? Откуда берется то?

Сформулируй правильно вопрос.

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

ты хоть проверял вот это **#\[font|font size=(1|2|3)\](.+?)\[\/font\]#is** что тут написано если на русский язык перевести?

Comment: $size это значение передаваемого атрибута. В примере я показал что сейчас есть, но оно не работает.

Comment: а где присвоение его идет в коде???

Comment: это то я и не знаю как осуществить.

Comment: для начала почитать документацию и разобраться какими функциями что можно делать!

Answer (score 1):

На боевом не проверял, но идея вот такая:

```
preg_match("#\[font|font size=(1|2|3)\](.+?)\[\/font\]#is", $text, $matches);
$size=$matches[1];

switch($size){
case '1': $f='font-style:10pt;';
case '2': $f='font-style:11pt;';
}
```